# Diagnosing as possible GPS issue with a Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, gps

My Nexus 5 has developed some GPS oddities that lead me to wonder if I've dropped it one time too many. I write this question to ask for some diagnostic procedure to tell.

Situations:

- Inability to get a GPS signal across much of Massachusetts for an afternoon.
- Landing in Washington, DC, and having location services place me in Phoenix, AZ.
- Walking along the sidewalk using Maps and having it decide that I'm going the opposite direction from my actual progress.

Yet nothing is complaining at me (except in the first case, where Sygic and Maps did complain about lack of a GPS lock.)

Is there anything I can do to determine if, in fact, something is broken, bent, or otherwise malfunctional?